# Is there a way to retrieve the tab order of HTML elements in Java?

Tags: java, gwt

Right now we have an element on the page that is not allowing users to tab out of it. The element was created in Java as a GWT component, I don't really know too much about GWT so I can't really describe it further.

Anyways, I know where I need to tell the component to tab to the next element in the tab order, but I don't know what commands to use to do so. Is there a way to retrieve the tab order of HTML elements in Java? If there is, I can just pick the next element in the list and set it to be focussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GWT `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element` you can access and set the tabIndex value of any GWT component (i.e. html element). If you're using a `Widget` class you can use `myWidget.getElement().getTabIndex()` and `setTabIndex(1)`.

In HTML you cannot just pick the next element with the tab out of the box, you can however maintain the tab indexes order in the order you expect.